# Saving a Powershell Object across Sessions

Tags: powershell, session

I currently have a project in powershell which interacts with a REST API, and the first step after opening a new powershell session is to authenticate myself which creates a websession object which is then used for subsequent API calls.

I was wondering what the best way of going about storing this token object across all Powershell sessions, because right now if I authenticate myself and then close & reopen powershell I need to re-authenticate which is rather inconvenient. I would like the ability to in theory authenticate once and then whenever I open up powershell be able to use my already saved websession object. At the moment I store this websession object in `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.PrivateData.Session`

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What kind of object is the token? String? Use `Export-CLIXML`

Comment: I guess token is a bad way to describe it, technically it is a WebRequestSession object because it is then passed back with the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet in the WebSession parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've written a number of PowerShell Modules which interact with REST APIs on the web so I've had to tackle this very problem!

The technique I liked to use involves storing the object within the user's local credential store, as seen in my [PSReddit PowerShell Module](https://github.com/1RedOne/PSReddit).

First, to export your password in an encrypted state.  We need to do this using both the ConvertTo and ConvertFrom cmdlets.

**Why both cmdlets?**

`ConvertTo-SecureString` makes our plaintext into an Encrypted Object, but we can't export that.  We then use `ConvertFrom-SecureString` to turn the encrypted object back into encrypted text, which we can export.

I'm going to start with my very secure password of ham.

```
$password = "ham"
$password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | 
  ConvertFrom-SecureString | Export-CliXML $Mypath\Export.ps1xml
```

At this point, I've got a file on disk which is encrypted.  If someone logs on to the machine they can't decrypt it, only I can.  If someone copies it off of the machine, they still can't decrypt it.  Only me, only here.

**How do we decrypt the text?**

Now, assuming we want to get the same plain text back out to use late, we can add this to our PowerShell Profile, you can import your password like so.

```
$pass = Import-CliXML $Mypath\Export.ps1xml | ConvertTo-SecureString
Get-DecryptedValue -inputObj $pass -name password

$password 
>"ham"
```

This will create a variable called `$password` containing your password.  The decryption depends on this function, so be sure it's in your profile: `Get-DecryptedValue`.

```
Function Get-DecryptedValue{
param($inputObj,$name)

            $Ptr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode($inputObj)
            $result = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($Ptr)
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeCoTaskMemUnicode($Ptr)
            New-Variable -Scope Global -Name $name -Value $result -PassThru -Force

}
```

Comment: Looks great! Thanks for this.

Comment: Hi @ju5tin, I just finished a big edit.  Make sure to refresh the code and try my newest edit.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks again!

Comment: If this helped, make sure to upvote and mark as answer!